# Best way to retrieve values in android mobile apps

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

While developing an android app, which is the best and efficient way to retrieve values from the below options:

- To get values from a property file or
- To get values from app shared preferences.

I like to know this based on memory usage and speed of retrieval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

IMO there's no better way as those two options would be used for different purpose.

- SharedPreference gives you an easy way to build a user editable Preference page via the PreferenceActivity and to share preference trough your application.
- For other purpose as user editable settings you could use Properties files to store data.

---

For properties you have two good examples here:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/
http://myossdevblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/reading-properties-files-on-android.html

For SharedPreference see here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

An example:

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
final String yourPref = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.settings_tag_your_pref), "");
```

or if you don't want to define a tag in string:

```
final String yourPref = sharedPreferences.getString("your_pref", "");
```

Comment: Resus, I am actually asking which is the good and efficient way to retrieve values in the above two